# Delete docker images from docker hub

Tags: azure, docker, dockerhub

How can i delete last 10 tags of the images in dockerhub from public or private repo? I am using azure container registry for saving images

Answer (score 0):

## !/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
        az acr repository show-tags -n {container registry name} --repository {repo name} --top $i --orderby time_asc | xargs -I X az acr repository delete -n {container registry name} -t {repo name}:X --yes

done